# Disable customer dashboard

Tags: customer

How can I completely disable the customer dashboard after login and after customer registration ?

After that I want to write only a success message.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? Customer logs in ... and then?

Comment: Do you want them to be redirected somewhere else, or do you want them to never see the dashboard and all related functionality?

Comment: It seems you don't want to display dashboard at all. And wanna give permission to view all other details right? If yes you can do that from System->permissions->roles. look here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-admin-users-roles

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt; @benmarks: I want that the customer never see the dashboard and all related functionalities, and that he will redirected to the homepage.

I am using Magento ver. 1.6.2.0
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting a user back to the page he come from after logging in is fairly easy.
This can be done via `System > Configuration > Customer` section.

Rewriting after login will take some more effort. From what I can see this quickly you will need to overwrite the customer controller, saving the customer and afterwards outputting a custom success page in your extensions controller

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be easier achieved, when just adding a url rewrite for

```
customer/account/dashboard
customer/address/index
customer/address/edit
...
```

and so on to whatever page you want them forwarded.